# How to create "FlashCards" with Actions on Google (add it to a DialogFlow project)

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to get the Flashcards features  following this sample : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjpbu4y6F_M

But the option doesn't appear!

How do I get this feature ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

The first is that the video you reference uses an older version of the Action console. To start building a template app, you would go to https://console.actions.google.com/, create the new project, and go to Actions on the left navigation, then click the "Add your first action" button.

[image]

A new box will pop up prompting what kind of Action you want to create. Scroll down the options on the left till you get to the "Templates" group, select "Flash cards" and then the "Build" link

[image]

You'll get a new box which follows roughly the same pattern as the video describes.

[image]

But here is where you encounter your other problem. You can select the language for this template in the upper left corner, but you'll see that for Flash cards, your options are... very limited... right now

[image]

The Trivia game template has more language options, but it still doesn't have all of the available languages for the Assistant.

Finally, once you start with one development approach (Templates, Dialogflow, Actions SDK) you can't add or switch to a different one. So you can't mix Templates and Dialogflow. The code for the Flash Cards aren't currently available, although Google has released them in the past for older versions.

Comment: Ok, But this is when you create your first Action... What if a already have a project ¿?... by example linked with dialogflow

Comment: Updated the answer to explain - but it isn't possible to mix Templates and Dialogflow.